# Converting QGIS layer to Gephi?

Tags: qgis

I want to convert a QGIS layer to Gephi. Im not sure what steps I need to take to make this happen. Currently I have a layer with numerous trials (edges). And I will be using water holes as nodes.

However I'm not sure how to set the data up to convert and import the data into Gephi software?

Comment: Gephi can import CSV files and QGIS can export CSV files. [This page] explains how the CSV should be formatted. Have you tried exporting a CSV from QGIS and importing it into Gephi? If that didn't work, did you try opening the CSV in Excel and re-organizing it to meet Gephi's expected format? Please [edit] your question to indicate what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Is it a flow-map you're after? If so, you might find [my previous answer to a similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/160467/55203) useful.

Comment: Thank you @StevenKay I think that Is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: @StevenKay I do have a question referring to your previous answer. I have imported the node file and that works fine using the geolayout plugin. However I am struggling on an edges table. My nodes are water holes and edges are animal trails, what would be the next step? As currently I have a csv trail file containing distance and angle of each trail. As not every single trail starts or ends at a waterhole?