# Flow map of commuters using QGIS

Tags: qgis, flow-map

I need to show in QGIS the a flow map of commuters in a municipality of Italy, Bari. In a CSV file I know the place they come from (a field called ORIG) and the place where they go (the field DEST) and the total number of them QGIS (TOTALE). In a shapefile I have the points with the coordinates; in this file the reference field is called SEZ.
Since I'm a bit ignorant in Python and SQL, could you please tell me a simple way to write few lines that would let me show in the map with lines where they come from and where they go? I would also crate lines with different width depending on the total number of commuters (the field called TOTALE). 
I tried to create a virtual layer selecting, from the CSV, the fields I would like to show, then joining the CSV with the shapefile. But it didn't work. I think I'm not writing the code in the correct way. I saw there is a plug-in as well, Map Flow, but I need to create a matrix that is too long to write down.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.StackExchange, Gabriele! If you followed the instructions in https://anitagraser.com/2019/05/04/flow-maps-in-qgis-no-plugins-needed/, we need to see your SQL query and your attribute tables to help figure out what's going wrong

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160350/how-to-create-flow-maps-in-qgis

Answer (score 3):

I had to do something similar once and I used [RT QSpider plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/rt_qspider/).

Steps:

1. Install the plugin RT QSpider in **Plugins > Manage and Install plugins**
2. Add the coordinates inside the attribute table of your shapefile of locations (if it is not already the case). To do so, you can use the tool in **Vector > Geometry Tools > Export/Add geometry columns**. It will create two new fields in the attribute table called **xcoord** and **ycoord**
3. Open your csv file in QGIS using **Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer**
4. Now you'll have to create 2 joins on your csv (one for the origin, and one for the destination). *Right click on your csv in the Layer panel > Properties > Joins*. Create the first join with the shapefile with geometry columns, join field should be SEZ and target field ORIG. Tick **choose which fields are joined** and select only **xcoord** and **ycoord**. Tick also Custom field name prefix and write **origin_**.
5. Create a second join using the same method but this time for the destination (select the DEST field in target field and write dest_ as prefix).

If the joins worked, you should have in the attribute table of your csv 4 new fields (origin_xcoord, origin_ycoord, dest_xcoord and dest_ycoord).

6. Select the csv in the Layer panel, and open the RT QSpider plugin in **Plugins > RT QSpider > Table to vector converter**.
7. Choose Line as Output Geometry and select the right fields for the starting and end points (origin and destination X and Y). Click on OK and you'll have your lines. Don't forget to save the result as a proper shapefile.

Then, for the styling of the line, go to **Symbology > Graduated**. Select **Method : Size** and select the TOTALE field to vary the width of the line depending on the number of commuters.

---

Just realized that the plugin is not (yet?) available for QGIS 3.x ... this method will only work in QGIS 2.x

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried what you said. A really nice method. So, I joined the fields you said and I had in my csv two fields with coordinates of both the origin and the destination. The first difficulty I met is that the RT QSpider plugin, in the modality Line, didn't read such coordinates. So I saved my csv (where THERE ARE the Orig_X Orig_Y Dest_X and Dest_Y) in another csv. With this other file I could run the Plug-in and insert the coordinates of origin and destination. But the shp so created didn't show anything. I have one explanation: it might be because in my case it is a re

Comment: Thanks a lot, at the end I was able to show what I wanted. I still have to refine the results, but it's a good start!